# How to Convert an interactive windows service to non interactive windows service?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

While searching for best practices on windows services, I found this [article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/821794/descriptions-of-some-best-practices-when-you-create-windows-services) 
 It is asking about making windows service non interactive. I don't undestand how to make a windows service non interactive.

I also am not able to understand if my service is interactive or non-interactive... So My Question is how do I know if it's interactive or non interactive?

In case, if my service is non-interactive, How do I convert the same into interactive service?

Comment: Does your service interact with the user in any way? Display message boxes, forms, require input etc? If so, then it's interactive.

Answer (score 0):

[Interactive service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/interactive-services) is a service that the user can interact with. With help of the UI (message boxes, dialogues, etc).

Noninteractive service is the opposite. It's just making calculations, checking for updates, etc.

Comment: So if my service is running in background, does that make it non-interactive or Do i need to set any other flags to indicate that?

Comment: @MaulikModi Windows services are non-interactive by default. You don't need to specify anything.

Answer (score 0):

The [article you mentioned](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/821794/descriptions-of-some-best-practices-when-you-create-windows-services) is somewhat dated. It says:

> When the interactive user is logged into the same instance of Windows
>   Services, window message attacks may occur. The interactive user may
>   inject and run the arbitrary code in an interactive services process.

That vulnerability, known as a [shatter attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shatter_attack), was addressed in Windows Vista through [Session 0 Isolation](https://www.coretechnologies.com/WindowsServices/FAQ.html#WhatIsSession0Isolation) — an arrangement that prohibits an interactive user from logging into Session 0 (where Windows Services run). You don't need to worry about that situation on any modern version of Windows.